# FastAPI: can I use Depends() for parameters in a POST, too?

Tags: python, post, dependency-injection, fastapi, depends

## Overview

I have created a class-based dependency, similar to what is in the amazing [FastAPI tutorial](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/classes-as-dependencies/#classes-as-dependencies_1).

## Problem

It works, *except* that the parameters in the dependency (the `Depends()` portion) are passed as query parameters, meaning that they are part of the URI/URL. I am using the class-based dependency as a means to simplify access to an Azure Datalake, so that the parameters in the Depends are at least somewhat secret.  So I would prefer for them to be in the POST portion.

## Question

Is there a way to use `Depends()`, but pass the class initialization parameters via the POST payload instead of in the URL path?

## Details

As an example:

The dependency class (just the initialization, which captures the dependency parameters):

```py
class DatalakeConnection(object):
    """Using FastAPI's `Depends` Dependency Injection, this class can have all
    elements needed to connect to a data lake."""

    def __init__(
        self,
        dir: str = my_typical_folder,
        container: str = storage_container.value,
    ):
        service_client = DataLakeServiceClient(
            account_url=storage_uri,
            credential=storage_credential,
        )
        self.file_system_client = service_client.get_file_system_client(
            file_system=container
        )
        self.directory_client = self.file_system_client.get_directory_client(dir)
        self.file_client = None
```

The FastAPI path function:

```py
@app.post("/datalake")  # I have no response model yet, but will add one
def predictions_from_datalake(
    query: schemas.Query, conn: DatalakeConnection = Depends()
):
    core_df = conn.read_excel(query.file_of_interest) # I create a DataFrame from reading Excel files
```

## Summary

As I said, this works, but the `dir` and `container` needed to initialize the class are forced into URL query parameters, but I would like for them to be key-value pairs in the request body of the POST:

[image: Image of the Swagger UI showing the dir as a query parameter instead of part of the POST body]

Comment: You could access the `Request` object within the function and do some stuff there, but I do not know if it's possible with classes. https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/using-request-directly/#use-the-request-object-directly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare them just like path operation body parameters. More info here [Singular values in body](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body-multiple-params/#singular-values-in-body):

```py
class DatalakeConnection(object):
    """Using FastAPI's `Depends` Dependency Injection, this class can have all
    elements needed to connect to a data lake."""

    def __init__(
            self,
            dir: str = Body("dir_default"),
            container: str = Body("container_default"),
    ):
        pass
```

Example of request body:

```
{
  "dir": "string",
  "container": "string"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use `Depends` with an existing class without updating the defaults on that class, you can create a function with the right signature and pass that to `Depends`.

```py
def _body_dependify(model_cls):
    """
    Hack around fastapi not supporting Body(...) parameters in dependencies unless
    you specify them in the function signature.
    """
    import functools
    import inspect
    from collections import OrderedDict

    signature = inspect.signature(model_cls)
    signature = signature.replace(return_annotation=model_cls)
    parameters = OrderedDict(signature.parameters)
    for parameter_name in list(parameters):
        parameter = parameters[parameter_name]
        if parameter.default is inspect.Parameter.empty:
            parameter = parameter.replace(default=Body())
        else:
            parameter = parameter.replace(default=Body(parameter.default))
        parameters[parameter_name] = parameter
    signature = signature.replace(parameters=parameters.values())

    @functools.wraps(model_cls)
    def build(*args, **kwargs):
        return model_cls(*args, **kwargs)

    build.__signature__ = signature
    return Depends(build)
```

Then in your endpoint, you can do:

```
@app.post("/datalake")  # I have no response model yet, but will add one
def predictions_from_datalake(
    query: schemas.Query, conn: DatalakeConnection = _body_dependify(DatalakeConnection)
):
    core_df = conn.read_excel(query.file_of_interest) # I create a DataFrame from reading Excel files
```

In the /docs page, the schema looks like this:

[image: screenshot of swagger /docs page from fastapi]

This also works with Pydantic models since they set the `__signature__` attribute.

Comment: See also the workaround for pydantic validation errors in `Depends` here: https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/1474#issuecomment-1160633178